# Reenter the new password in configured Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have configured HTC Hero phone with my Gmail account (username and password), and it is configured successfully. I have recently changed the password of this account from the Gmail website, so at the same time I have to change the password on my phone, but I do not see where to do this.

Without reentering the new password, I am not able to get/send mail. How do I enter the new password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some options:

1. Try hitting Menu -> Refresh in GMail, there should be a notification prompting you to re-enter the password.  If it's in the notification bar, pull it down and click it.
2. Clear the cache and data for all Google apps on your phone: Gmail, Gmail storage, Google Framework Services, Talk, Accounts, Play Store, etc. via `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`.
3. If your phone lets you, go to `Settings -> Accounts and sync` and remove and re-add the account.

Comment: +1 That's exactly what I did when I changed my password a while ago. The icon in the notification bar looked like a red triangle with an exclamation mark in it. Selecting that notification prompted me to enter the new password, and then all was ok.

Comment: 1 & 2, don't work for me and it won't let me remove the account. Are there any other options?

Comment: @Richard A factory reset, though that's extreme. I would try: (1) go into Airplane Mode (2) reboot (3) clear the data for all Google apps again and anything that seems account related (4) reboot again (5) re-connect to data or Wi-Fi (6) wait a few minutes and see if you get a notification (7) open Gmail and see if you get prompted.

Comment: @MatthewRead, thanks for trying, but no luck. Guess I'm going to have to factory reset. Think this is going to be my last Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use google apps for business and your services were part of the big migration fiasco then you might have found yourself in the same situation I was in.

After changing my google account password I somehow had a google apps account with my new password, and an old personal account with the same username, but old password.

If you can log into gmail using your old password, but are then prompted to rename your personal account or migrate services then this has probably happened to you.

I'd already migrated stuff previously, but I hadn't renamed my old account. I thought it would have died by now.

I logged into my old account using current user name and old password. When prompted to rename my old account I did so. The next time my phone tried to log in the username old password combo was no longer hooked up to an old account and it asked me to enter a new password.