# How do I change the password of my main Google account on a Droid X?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, password, google-account

I changed my Google Account password (on my computer).  I now need to change it on my Droid X.  I cannot figure out how to do this.

I Googled, and everyone says go to Settings > Accounts.  I did this, but there is nowhere to change the password there.  It only specifies four services that are syncing.  "Contacts" is throwing an error now, but, still, there is nowhere to change the password.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Gmail app?  Sometimes it prompts for the new password.

Comment: It does not prompt me.  Weirdly, it also doesn't throw an error.  It's not retrieving any mail, obviously, but it's not complaining about a failure to login, either.

Comment: OK, I would try point 2 in my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/android-reenter-the-new-password-in-configured-gmail-account-with-android-phone).

Comment: No luck.  GMail is now empty and keeps telling me my "email will appear shortly."  It never does.  No error, nothing.

Comment: Have you tried Matthew's point 3?  Basically remove the Google account and try to re-add it.

Comment: It will not let me remove it.  If I click on the account (in the list of accounts), I'm just shown the four items that are syncing.  Clicking any of them just toggles the sync for that item. The menu button just reveals an option for "Sync Now."

Comment: For some reason, it never prompted me for the new password. I had to hard reset the phone...seriously.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Settings -> Accounts and sync -> username@gmail.com`, press the Menu button, and click "Sync now"; it will prompt you to enter the credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the phone should have detected the password change and a notification should appear in the notification bar to ask for a new password. Are your phone connected to the internet? If the phone doesn't detect the password change, try rebooting the phone.

If the phone still aren't asking for password, try removing your account and readding again, go to Settings > Account > Remove Account:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (on my Samsung Galaxy Ace phone): I accessed Gmail app on my phone, which prompted me to retype my password (because I had previously changed it on a PC) then, bang ... Market app started.

Comment: It's great that this worked for you, but the questioner already said that he tried opening the Gmail app and it didn't prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.  Had all the same symptoms as the original questioner.  But I think I figured it out.  A Warning triangle came up on the Droid (where you see if you have missed calls, texts, etc.  Said Action Required for GMail.  Opened it up.  The message wasn't really clear, but it only gave me two options - Retry and Cancel.  Cancel didn't work (did nothing).  *Retry gave me the screen to enter the password.  Hope this is timely and it helps.*